# How to sort guava Multimap keys in reverse order?

Tags: java, dictionary, guava, multimap

I'm fairly new to Guava API and is trying to sort the keys of a `MultiMap` in reverse order or descending value. I'm initiating the `Map` in the following way:

```
ListMultimap<Date, Map<String, String>> listMultimap = MultimapBuilder.treeKeys().arrayListValues().build();
```

This sorts the keys in ascending. E.g.:

```
List multi map iteration: key -->Fri Jan 01 00:00:00 PST 2016   values -->[{test2=testval2}, {test3=testval3}]
List multi map iteration: key -->Sun Jan 01 00:00:00 PST 2017   values -->[{test1=testval1}]
List multi map iteration: key -->Mon Jan 01 00:00:00 PST 2018   values -->[{test0=testval0}]
List multi map iteration: key -->Tue Jan 01 00:00:00 PST 2019   values -->[{test4=testval4}]
```

I tried creating a custom Date `Comparator` with `TreeMultiMap`, but haven't figure a way to do it. This is not syntactically right,but just trying to demonstrate the idea.

```
static final Comparator<Date> DESC_ORDER = new Comparator<Date>() {
    public int compare(Date e1, Date e2) { 
        return e2.compareTo(e1);
    }
};

SortedSetMultimap<Date, Map<String, String>> treeMultimap = TreeMultimap.create(DESC_ORDER);
```

Any pointers will be appreciated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try using [`treeKeys(Comparator)`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/MultimapBuilder.html#treeKeys%28java.util.Comparator%29):

```
MultimapBuilder.treeKeys(DESC_ORDER).arrayListValues().build();
```

Comment: Thanks a ton, I don't know how I actually missed it :-)